# Firefox addon data sent in post firebug

Tags: ajax, firefox, post, firebug, onsubmit

I know that Firebug can display data sent by AJAX, but I cannot find way to see data sent by pressing button "Submit" on form of web page. Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebug also does this.  Look in the "Net" tab.  Each HTTP request is listed below it. Just click the + icon next to request your interested in and you can inspect the Request, Response, Post, HTML .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Firebug can do that. Simply click on "Persistent" in the [Network Tab](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel), so that the request doesn't vanish after the page reloads.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) for this.